# .NET open and edit an .accde database with password

Tags: .net, database, ms-access

We are coding an .NET app that needs to connect to an .accde database protected with a password that I already know, but there is no way to reach that aim, apparently is not possible.
   I write down this note here to seek for help in order to achieve that goal if possible. Anyone has had to face this kind of issue?
Thanks in advance to anyone that wants to give a clue!

Answer (score 0):

Using ODBC you just need to add a `PWD=` attribute to your connection string. The following works for me with the Access 2010 version of the Access ODBC driver:

```csharp
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string connStr = 
            @"DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};" +
            @"DBQ=C:\Users\Public\zzz.accde;" +
            @"PWD=whatever;";
    using (var conn = new OdbcConnection(connStr))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT txt FROM Table1";
            using (OdbcDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(rdr["txt"]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```